# Tk::Stderr empty text subwidget

Tags: perl, user-interface, tk-toolkit

I've written a perl/tk gui. The stderr & stdout write to a popup window, but I cannot clear the text when the popup window is destroyed (it is actually withdrawn). I could not install Tk::Stderr so I appended the module to the end of my script. Below is a working example.

I have added the following line to the Print subroutine, but it is overkill:

```
$text->delete('0.0', 'end');
```

My suspicion is that something could be added to the following line in the Populate subroutine:

```
$mw->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => [ $mw => 'withdraw']);
```

but I don't know what. I would appreciate any assistance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Tk;
# use Tk::Stderr; << ** pasted module after main ** - honyok

# create main window
my $mw = MainWindow->new;
$mw->InitStderr;
$mw->optionAdd("*font", "-*-calibri-normal-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-*-*");
$mw->protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW'=> sub{exit});
$mw->geometry( "100x100");
$mw->resizable(0,0);# not resizable
# create buttons
my $button1=$mw->Button(-text=>'STDERR',-command=>[sub{print STDERR "Writing to STDERR\n";}])->pack;
my $button2=$mw->Button(-text=>'STDOUT',-command=>[sub{print STDOUT "Writing to STDOUT\n";}])->pack;

MainLoop;
# =========================== end main ==================================


##==============================================================================
## Tk::Stderr - capture program standard error output
##==============================================================================
## $Id: Stderr.pm,v 1.2 2003/04/01 03:58:42 kevin Exp $
##==============================================================================
#require 5.006;
package Tk::Stderr;
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw($VERSION @ISA);
($VERSION) = q$Revision: 1.2 $ =~ /Revision:\s+(\S+)/ or $VERSION = "0.0";
use base qw(Tk::Derived Tk::MainWindow);

use Tk::ROText;
use Tk::Frame;

##==============================================================================
## Populate
##==============================================================================
sub Populate {
    my ($mw, $args) = @_;
    my $private = $mw->privateData;
    $private->{ReferenceCount} = 0;
    $private->{Enabled} = 0;

    $mw->SUPER::Populate($args);

    $mw->withdraw;
    $mw->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => [ $mw => 'withdraw']);
    my $f = $mw->Frame(
        Name => 'stderr_frame',
    )->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);

    my $text = $f->Scrolled(
        'ROText',
        Name => 'stderr_text',
        -scrollbars => 'se',
        -label=>'Output/Errors',
        -wrap => 'none'
        #-background=>'slate grey'
    )->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);

    $mw->Advertise('text' => $text);
    $mw->ConfigSpecs(
        '-title' => [ qw/METHOD title Title/, "truGrid" ],
    );

    $mw->Redirect(1);
    return $mw;
}

##==============================================================================
## Redirect
##==============================================================================
sub Redirect {

    my ($mw, $boolean) = @_;
    my $private = $mw->privateData;
    my $old = $private->{Enabled};

    if ($old && !$boolean) {
        untie *STDOUT;# ** hacked this line ** - honyok
        untie *STDERR;
        $SIG{__WARN__} = 'DEFAULT';
    } elsif (!$old && $boolean) {
        tie *STDOUT, 'Tk::Stderr::Handle', $mw;# ** hacked this line ** - honyok
        tie *STDERR, 'Tk::Stderr::Handle', $mw;
        $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print STDOUT @_ };# ** hacked this line ** - honyok
        $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { print STDERR @_ };
    }
    $private->{Enabled} = $boolean;
    return $old;
}


##==============================================================================
## DecrementReferenceCount
##==============================================================================
sub DecrementReferenceCount {
    my ($mw) = @_;
    my $private = $mw->privateData;

    if (--$private->{ReferenceCount} <= 0) {
        $mw->destroy;
    }
}

##==============================================================================
## IncrementReferenceCount
##==============================================================================
sub IncrementReferenceCount {
    my ($mw) = @_;
    my $private = $mw->privateData;

    ++$private->{ReferenceCount};
}


package MainWindow;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $error_window;

##==============================================================================
## InitStderr
##==============================================================================
sub InitStderr {
    my ($mw, $title) = @_;

    unless (defined $error_window) {
        $error_window = Tk::Stderr->new;
        $error_window->title($title) if defined $title;
    }
    $error_window->IncrementReferenceCount;
    $mw->OnDestroy([ 'DecrementReferenceCount' => $error_window ]);
    return $mw;
}

##==============================================================================
## StderrWindow
##==============================================================================
sub StderrWindow {
    return $error_window;
}

##==============================================================================
## RedirectStderr
##==============================================================================
sub RedirectStderr {
    my ($mw, $boolean) = @_;

    unless (defined $error_window) {
        $mw->InitStderr if $boolean;
        return;
    }
    return $error_window->Redirect($boolean);
}


##==============================================================================
## Define the handle that actually implements things.
##==============================================================================
BEGIN {
    package Tk::Stderr::Handle;
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    ##==========================================================================
    ## TIEHANDLE
    ##==========================================================================
    sub TIEHANDLE {
        my ($class, $window) = @_;
        bless \$window, $class;
    }

    ##==========================================================================
    ## PRINT
    ##==========================================================================
    sub PRINT {
        my $window = shift;
        my $text = $$window->Subwidget('text');
        $text->insert('end', $_) foreach (@_);
        $text->see('end');
        $$window->deiconify;
        $$window->raise;
        $$window->focus;
        $$window->update;# ** hacked this line ** - honyok
    }

    ##==========================================================================
    ## PRINTF
    ##==========================================================================
    sub PRINTF {
        my ($window, $format) = splice @_, 0, 2;

        $window->PRINT(sprintf $format, @_);
    }
}
1;
##==============================================================================
## $Log: Stderr.pm,v $
## Revision 1.2  2003/04/01 03:58:42  kevin
## Add RedirectStderr method to allow redirection to be switched on and off.
##
## Revision 1.1  2003/03/26 21:48:43  kevin
## Fix dependencies in Makefile.PL
##
## Revision 1.0  2003/03/26 19:11:32  kevin
## Initial revision
##==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered on another forum.)

Replace:

```
$mw->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => [ $mw => 'withdraw' ]);
```

with:

```
$mw->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => [ $mw => 'OnWithdraw' ]);
```

Define the subroutine:

```
sub OnWithdraw{
    my $window = shift;
    my $text   = $window->Subwidget('text');
    $text->delete('0.0', 'end');
    $window->withdraw;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the behavior of leaving the content of the text widget is correct. 
When closing the popup, the widget is not destroyed, but kept intact and any new information is appended.

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behavior but I want to clear the text on withdraw.